# Testing Battery Usage

Tags: android, testing

I want to test how my application effects the battery of a phone/tablet.

Are there any testing tools which will allow me to do so?

For example, I want to test which modules of my application are consuming the most amount of battery, etc.

Comment: +1 This is good question, I think more people should be concerned with this.  I would guess that it would be hard to measure the battery performance on a per module basis.  I imagine you would only be able to get a average usage of the whole system over time.

Comment: During one of the BUILD keynotes, they showed a real-time graph of power usage in a tablet running Windows 8. The graph was updating on a millisecond basis and with high accuracy, but the monitoring computer had direct wires connected to the Samsung tablet that was taken apart. They said they used this method to assess power usage of all aspects of the OS and applications. I'm sure there are similar tools for Android, but they might also require some hardware tinkering.

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5124013/324625

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a new tool which comes with Android 5.0.

You can run

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats > dump.txt
```

To get the full battery dump of you device. You also can add some options like `--unplugged` (only output data since last unplugged) or `--charged` (only output data since last charged). You can also add a packagename to get informations for this package/app only:

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats --unplugged your.package.name > dump.txt
```

The part `> dump.txt` put everything into a file (maybe just works on Windows, not sure. But you can just leave it away, the dump will be printed right in the console where you can copy it and put it in a file).

This works just if you have a device with Android 5.x.
If you have a device with a lower level you can try to use

```
adb shell bugreport > bugreport.txt
```

But this file will be very very big. (~8mb+)

After creating this file you can use the [Historian Tool of Google](https://github.com/google/battery-historian)

To use it you have to install Python 2.7.9 and run following command

```
python /path/to/historian.py dump.txt > battery.html
```

This will create a battery.html file where you can see the data in a more usefull formatting.

Last thing: If you want to reset the stats of the battery dump just call

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats --reset
```

(just works with Android 5.x)

Comment: Also works on pre-Kitkat devices, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24785282/1045475. Also try script: https://github.com/alex-yh99/battery-historian/blob/master/battery_test.py

Comment: is there any way that we can run adb command in android application. tried in stackoverflow but haven't get any success. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119721/run-adb-command-from-application-using-java

Answer (score 22):

In practice, I believe most apps that have power problems, also have 'CPU' problems.  That is, a profile of your application's CPU usage is probably a good approximation of your battery consumption.  There are caveats and exceptions if, for example, your app is doing something expensive with the GPU, the wireless network, storage, etc, and that expensive operation isn't taking much CPU time.

Here's an interesting blog about a "Power Tutor" app that provides a more precise measurement on a running system than the built-in battery app:
http://gigaom.com/mobile/android-power-consumption-app/.  I haven't tried it.

For another level of detail, here is a paper that breaks down which components of a phone suck the most juice (note the paper is from 2010): http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix10/tech/full_papers/Carroll.pdf
(Just skip to section 5 to read their results). They say the screen brightness is the biggest culprit.

If the screen brightness is the biggest culprit, be sure to set that to a fixed level if you are measuring your own application's usage.

If you're really interested in measuring power consumption, you can follow their methodology (which invovles opening the phone and physically attaching measuring devices.)

Comment: GPS also consumes much battery!

Answer (score 4):

The question that you have asked is a research topic right now.
There is some on going research on tracing fine grained power usage i.e tracing power usage on thread or subroutine basis.\

eprof is one tool developed by some university grads.

you can find some papers on this topic here : http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~pathaka/pubs.html

I am working on the same thing, I will surely notify you if anything usable comes for normal users.

Comment: It's forbidden to visit that link. Could you provide a working one?

Comment: Here's a paper by Pathak http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~nieh/teaching/e6998/papers/eprof_eurosys2012.pdf - it may have been in the broken link.

Comment: Both links in the answer andthe comment no longer exist

Answer (score 1):

As of Android 2.3.3 the system has a native Battery monitor.

Settings -> About Phone -> Battery use

Comment: Thank you for the answer, hunterp. But I need a more detailed analysis of the battery usage so I can figure out where and how to improve my app's battery usage.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there is no real tool to test it since it can't be precisely mesured. If you take an iPhone, you will see the battery count go from 40% to 30%, then stay there for a while, go down to 20%, lower to 15%, go up to 25%, Go back to 20% ECT.
What you could do is charge your phone for an extended period of time, to make sure it is fully charged, and then use your app until the phone closes, and note the amount of time it took.
Now do this with another version and see the result. 
Basicly you'll have to play the MasterMind game with it if you want to do the less tests as possible.
Also, if the change isn't easy to see, it is probably not very important.

Comment: Your proposed method is not accurate as well. What if during the second run the device itself (OS) or other installed apps will decide to update some data (backup contacts, send usage logs, check for updates etc...) and you will waste battery on wifi/3g connection and data transfer?

Answer (score 0):

We performed similar testing to know how my application is responsible for battery consumption  of Nexus5 phone .

But unfortunately we could not get help from any tool but it was  mostly based on  manual testing .

We identified some modules in app which were suspected for more battery consumption.

1. Location awareness module which uses GPS .
2. Upload module which uses network connection runs a background operation for long time.
3. Video creation module which also make CPU busy due to background operation.
   and so on...

Finally  after 3-4 round of testing we had some trend in data and we were able to identify the module which was big culprit for battery consumption.

Basically there will be more battery consumption if something is keeping CPU busy more time.  So we can think of module which have background operations, network related operations.

As of now I can not find any tool which could tell above testing result in a particular app.

Hope my experience would be beneficial for requirement statement in original question.

Comment: Could you please explain the steps which were performed to find the modules consuming battery?