# Android L battery historian.par tool missing

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Since Google made the updated SDK for Android L available on their website. I have been trying to test the new battery historian feature. The Google API overview [website](http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html) claims that the tool is available under sdk/tools. Unfortunately even after ensuring that I have updated the SDK completely I am unable to find the tool anywhere. Does anyone know how I can access this tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not missing it's available at:

https://github.com/google/battery-historian

note: it currently requires the dependency, monsoon.py which is not in AOSP (yet) - but can be found here:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/src/+/master/tools/telemetry/telemetry/core/platform/power_monitor/monsoon_power_monitor.py

Comment: Have you tried integrating historian.py with Power monitor. If so what steps did u follow.

Comment: Well, it looks like this is the python script that should do it. However, I think it requires a hardware component like the Monsoon Power Monitor to provide the out file (as in monsoon.out seen in the comments section of the python script). Google's documentation seems to have conveniently left this out and the location they mention in the documentation does not have it. I could be wrong and in such a case if someone can point me to some resource explaining how this thing actually works, I would be grateful to them. But thanks for pointing me to this script.

Comment: you're right, not in AOSP (yet) - but chromium has it at:
/tools/telemetry/telemetry/core/platform/profiler/monsoon.py

Comment: and not to forget, the hardware component as mentioned in the script "Interface for a USB-connected Monsoon power meter. http://msoon.com/LabEquipment/PowerMonitor/" But thanks for pointing this out. I will see if I can get my hands on the hardware, so that I can make this work.

Comment: Note: The latest battery-historian update on 7/10 works - they've synched with their internal version.

Answer (score 9):

If you like to see the battery history data with KitKat and below devices, fork the [battery-historian](https://github.com/google/battery-historian) and then run the following:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys batterystats --reset

>> run some test. either manual or with espresso, or monkeyrunner ... <<

$ adb bugreport > bugreport.txt
$ ./historian.py bugreport.txt > out.html

>> open out.html with your favorite browser <<
```

If you generated a power consumption file with either monsoon or any other tool, you can add this file (lines of  ) by passing it with the `-p` parameter

**Edit**
A better and faster way to get the bugreport is by using:

```
# create battery stats table
adb shell dumpsys batterystats > bugreport
# append the creation time, which is way more accurate
echo "== dumpstate: `adb shell date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" >> bugreport
```

Comment: I can get a correct dump this way from a KitKat (4.4.2) device (about half a meg or so long), but historian.py produces essentially empty output from it (3KB file that just says "Cannot read property 'valueOf' of null").

Comment: @RespawnedFluff you have the wrong Python! You need 2.7.9 instead of 3.x - but in my case I can create the dump while using "adb shell dumpsys batterystats <package> > dump.txt" but if I run the historian command it is stuck forever and never generates the html file.

Comment: No, I didn't use 3.x, but 2.7.8. I doubt anything was added in 2.7.9 to fix that...

Comment: Was just a guess because I had the same problem with 3.x

Comment: What exactly are you (Informatic0re) trying to  say anyway? Adb worked for us both. However the historian.py script failed us both but in different ways: almost empty output for me (just a sekeleton) vs. not finishig for you?

Comment: Sometimes it is working sometimes not. Now I use bugreport to get the dump and after this I am using the historian.py to create the html and it worked. But sometimes it doesn't work and the historian.py is stuck at some point and don't create a html file

Comment: @joecks Thanks for your answer! I've written a script for pre-Kitkat usage: https://github.com/alex-yh99/battery-historian/blob/master/battery_test.py