# What is the android standard or benchmark for battery drain by an application?

Tags: power-management, battery

I was working on my phone-book application and recorded battery drain for 1 hour.
It drained to 5 % for 1 hour. I wanted to know what is the android standard or what is the android benchmark for battery drain for specific time of an application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is my Android App Draining Battery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124013/is-my-android-app-draining-battery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no answer for this, because your app had barely any effect at all on the battery during that time.

The device is on and awake, powering the processor at speed, generating, and displaying graphics. You app is doing very few calculations compared to what is going on behind the scenes.

Battery life also varies by device, battery health, backlight level, wifi, bluetooth, nfc, and other factors, one of which is your app, very low on the list of power consumption.

Once you start calculating Pi, or doing other intense calculations, you will not see a significant power consumption due to your app alone.