# how I can collect battery info for my app in android？

Tags: android, battery

I want to collect how much power use for a app in android. I find that **BatteryStatsHelper class** in source code, but it need **android.permission.BATTERY_STATS**. I put it in to AndroidManifest.xml, but it not work. I search this issues and someone say that this permission only give system app. I have other idea to do this. what other good idea for me ?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get battery level and state in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android)

Comment: @Sanoop hi , I want to get battery use for my app, such as ...mA in a few time

Comment: @guodongcao what's issue are you facing ?

Comment: @Sanoop I want to monitor  my app for a version and found it if consume too much power than last version. if too much ,I should send a report to my server

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124013/is-my-android-app-draining-battery) Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

You should register broadcast like this:

```
public class BatteryActivity extends Activity{

private BatteryReceiver batteryReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.battary);

    batteryReceiver = new BatteryReceiver();
    IntentFilter batteryFilter = new IntentFilter();
    batteryFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, batteryFilter);
}


private class BatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        int level = arg1.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        Log.i("Battery", "当前电池的剩余电量为：" +  level + "%");
    }

}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(batteryReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
 }
}
```

then in `onReceive()` ,you can `arg1.getIntExtra("",0)` ,the first parmas can like these:

- "level" (int)  residual capacity
- "scale" (int) the maximun
- "voltage" (int) voltage
- "temperature" (int) temperature
- "techonology" (String) battery stype
- "status"(int) charged state
- etc..

Hope can help you.

Comment: hi, I want to get how much power my app use