# Measured sleep current is higher than standard current while application is running

Tags: android

My App was rejected from samsung gallexy seller store because of following issue

**Measured sleep current is higher than standard current while application is running**

please help me how to find and solve this issue in android

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124013/is-my-android-app-draining-battery

Answer (score 0):

Battery Historian is a tool to analyze battery consumers using Android "bugreport" files.

Reference Site : https://github.com/google/battery-historian

Comment: can you please explain how to use this